# Indicate mode frequency in an barplot on ordinate (y axis)

Tags: r, plot

I have long been looking on the web but I only found solutions applying to Stata. But there must be a solution to R (I hope).

How can I label the upper end of the y axis of a barplot with the most frequent observation of the plotted variable?
Let's find some random data

```
scores <- sample(1:6,40,replace=TRUE)
```

and calculate and plot the frequency:

```
frqncy <- table(scores)
plot(frqncy)
```

Now I want the frequency of the mode to be last number on the ordinate. But

```
mode_freq <- as.numeric(max(frqncy))
plot(frqncy, ylim=c(0,mode_freq))
```

doesn't affect the labelling. Who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest you do some reading of a decent R graphics tutorial site like here:
http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

The basic idea is to make your plot without a y-axis (`yaxt="n"`) and then manually add an `axis()` with specified points of your own choosing:

```
plot(frqncy,yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,mode_freq))
axis(2,at=0:mode_freq,las=1)
```

Comment: Wonderful! I must admit that I've never seen that site although I know statmethods.net. Thanks for that link!